# Check uncheck switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, switchery

Hello I am using [abpetkov/switchery](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) to render those beautiful switches. There is a problem that I am facing which is that I want to enable or disable switches using jquery and by enable and disable I mean check and uncheck. I can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody tell me how to do it I'm rendering it like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='record-call' data-render='switchery' data-theme='default' id="abcd"  /></td>
      </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

the problem that I'm facing is whenever I try to check or uncheck the switcher like this `$( "#hour-1" ).prop( "checked", true );` it checks/unchecks the check box but does not effects the switcher

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: @PavanTeja I have added the code

Comment: And the JS is where?

Comment: @xkcd149 in the same folder where my js file is located

Comment: Well we need to see the relevant bits to be able to help you.  Please check this... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @garden share your implementation in plunker or jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the onchange  event and then trigger the click event. I kind of did it like this 
`e.next.click()` You must be wondering why I wrote next. Well if you inspect you input box you will see that there is a span underneath the input box. that is your switcher. just trigger the click event on that.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='record-call' data-render='switchery' data-theme='default' id="abcd"  onchange="fun(this)"/></td>
      </td>
    </tr>   
</table>


function fun(e){
   e.next.click()
}
```

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask anything if you have any confusion.

Comment: thanks man you were a great help.This is exactly what I was looking for